# A table of friends - store user ids or usernames?

Tags: mysql

I have a pretty typical user table setup for my web application:

```
user_id  |  username
--------------------
    0          greg
    1          john
   ...         ...
```

Both fields are indexed and unique, so I can look up a user by id or username quickly.

I want to keep a friends table, and am not sure whether to store the user_id values or usernames in that table:

```
user_id_1   |   user_id_2
--------------------------

            or

username_1  |   username_2
--------------------------
```

I am going to want to get a list of friends for a user, so it would be convenient to immediately have the usernames in the friends table instead of doing a join on the users table:

```
select * from friends where username_1 = 'greg';
```

If I'm storing user ids, I need to do a join then to get the usernames - will that be costly?:

```
select * from friends 
    where user_id_1 = x 
    join users where user_id = { all those results }
```

Using user ids allows me to let users change usernames flexibly, but I'm not letting them do that anyway. Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join on the IDs won't be too bad. The ID may be smaller to store on disk. Also, I would imagine a list of friends would have something other than just user names, in which case, you have to join no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you said, using id semantics means you can change the username without having to deal with cascading effects. For most cases PK / UNQ + FK indexes will make joins thundering fast, but you may have a point for huge tables (for which you will eventually need some kind of external index, or other tool anyway).

Comment: Oh, and you can avoid that inner query with something like: `select * from friends f inner join users u ON (f.user_id2 = u.user_id) where f.user_id1 = [id]`

Comment: Yeah my users probably won't have more than 50 friend each.

Answer (score 1):

The ID will be smaller if you use numeric values. Also the index search will be faster. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) you'll find the data types for MySQL 5.0.

Also I don't know how are you using index, but I'd recommend to add and auto-increment field. You can do that to a table, for an integer index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `Database`.`tableName` ADD COLUMN `indexName` INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```